# swift: How do I change the background color, when it is already a color to start with?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, background-color

I am trying to change the color of the background of the **view** (game play) when a button is pressed. using this: **self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()** however this works (the background is turning red) only when the backgroundColor is already set to the default color before running. when i try to set the backgroundColor to red when the backgroundColor is already yellow (or any other color set before hand in Xcode, not programatically), it does not work. The background stays yellow.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import iAd
class gamePlay: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate {


    @IBAction func b4(sender: AnyObject) {

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        print("background is red")
    }


    @IBOutlet var adBanner2: ADBannerView!

    var flag = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if flag == "hard"{

            print("hard mode")
        }

        else if flag == "normal"{

            print("normal mode")

        }

        adBanner2.hidden = true
        adBanner2.delegate = self
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    }

    func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

    }

    func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    NSLog("error 2")
    }

    func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
        adBanner2.hidden = false
    }



}
```

Comment: so you are saying that background colour change works when u set it programmatically but not when u do it in Xcode ?

Comment: what is view in the code ? are you referring to self.view or is view an iboutlet of an uiview ?

Comment: based on how this question is currently configured and presented my response is "nope, not true", as Mr. T is kind of also saying. From this, can you please elaborate and update the original question? Include bold-titled sections of 'Initial Configuration' (include storyboard or programmatic and FULL details) 'Target Action' (location, timing, initiating action, response), 'Current Action' (how you implemented the Target Action), 'Observed Response'. Doing this can get us to resolution as quickly as possible :)

Comment: thanks for letting me know, it is now edited. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are setting the correct view to yellow in the Xcode interface builder? I don't know how your view hierarchy looks like but try the following:

```
@IBAction func b4(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("background was \(self.view.backgroundColor)")
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    print("background is now \(self.view.backgroundColor)")
}
```

It should print yellow first and red after that. If it does not show yellow first, then you were setting the wrong view to yellow in the interface builder (one that maybe entirely covers your whole background view or similar, so you don't see the color of the background view).